# How to deal with multi-day (and out-of-office) appointments in Outlook once marked as tentative?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, out-of-office

Often coworkers will send multi-day out of office notices in Outlook. (Or, similarly, multi-day events.)

I accepted one as "tentative" somewhat accidentally.

However, now my calendar shows shaded tentative status everywhere they are away. I changed to decline, and now it's gone.. (This is bad since I do not see it at all and I'd like to see what days they are gone.)

Part a: Aside from Declining (which removes it entirely) how can I take away the "tentative" state?
Part b: What is the best practice for these OOO (out of office) notices? I am guessing we leave them as is (and do not respond as accept, tentative nor decline)?

Comment: If it is tentative, you can accept it as firm. You do not wish to delete, so either accept it, or leave it as is.

Comment: The calendar invite should be in the folder where deleted emails are

Comment: Agree with John, we could accept the meeting to keep it on your calendar. By the way, what's the account that you are working with? If you are working with exchange account, it would be better to ask the coworkers set their oof status directly when he need to leave, so that it won’t take up other people’s calendar time.